# Write text into a Word table, but get a runtime error 5941 if I use long variables, such as .Cells(lCol,lRow)

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell

I naively thought I could use the following to put text in a specific cell of a Word table, but it doesn't work (runtime error). However, if I put specific numbers equal to the variables it works fine. Is there a way to use long variables as specified in the MS docs? Thanks for any help...

```
    Private Sub SubmitCB1_Click()
    Dim vText As String
    Dim tabNum As Long
    Dim rowNum As Variant
    Dim colNum As Variant
      vText = Me.vNameCB1.Value
      tabNum = 3
      rowNum = 2
      colNum = 4
      Call InsertTextInCell(tabNum, rowNum, colNum, vText)
    End Sub


    Private Sub InsertTextInCell(tNum, rNum, cNum, vText)
      If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= tNum Then
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(tNum)
          .Cell(rNum, cNum).Range.InsertAfter vText
        End With
      End If
    End Sub
```

Based on the MS Docs, I was expecting the numbers could be replaced with Long variable names. I've reviewed many examples online and all seem to specify the numbers in the cell directly. So maybe it's not possible to use variables, or they have to be specified in a different way(?)

Tried this with same problem:

```
Private Sub SubmitCB1_Click()
Dim vText As String
Dim tabNum As Long
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim colNum As Long
  vText = Me.vNameCB1.Value
  tabNum = 3
  rowNum = 2
  colNum = 4
  Call insertBottomRow(tabNum)
  Call InsertTextInCell(tabNum, rowNum, colNum, vText)
End Sub

Private Sub insertBottomRow(tNum)
Dim theTable As Table
Dim theNewRow As Row
If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= tNum Then
  Set theTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(tNum)
  Set theNewRow = theTable.Rows.Add
End If
End Sub


Private Sub InsertTextInCell(tNum As Long, rNum As Long, cNum As Long, vText)
 If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= tNum Then
 With ActiveDocument.Tables(tNum)
    .Cell(rNum, cNum).Range.InsertAfter vText
'   .Delete
 End With
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note - I tried Long variables - as well as Variant (shown here) - just experimenting.

Comment: Try `Private Sub InsertTextInCell(tNum As Long, rNum As Long, cNum As Long, vText As String)`. It is important to specify the types of your variables. Some functions and properties may not accept `Variant` values

Comment: Hmm - I just had a thought, and put numbers directly in the call routine and that worked, so maybe it is something to do with the call method. I'm not passin gthe parameters correctly?

Comment: Hi Toddleson - yes, I initially had Long, but I'll try that. I tried specifying dimensions in the subroutine, but got an error that they were duplicates.

Comment: Even if you call them `Long` in `SubmitCB1_Click`, if you don't specify that the parameters of `InsertTextInCell` are `Long` then they are accepted as `Variant`. See the example in my other comment for how to define the types of the parameters.

Comment: Tried that, but no - same issue.

Comment: does your table have at least 2 rows and at least 4 columns? Are there merged cells in the table?

Comment: Hi Ike, yes - and it works fine if I specify actual numbers (so Call InsertTextInCell(tabNum, 3,4, vText) works.

Comment: I tested your code - it works for me. On which row do you get the error? The code is within `ActiveDocument` or within another document?

Comment: This error 5491 in my test raises, when column number (colNum) is greater than actual table columns count. When row number  (rowNum) is greater then actual rows count,  InsertAfter has an effect on last row.

Comment: Hi, and thanks so much for the work on this. OK, to be sure there's no issue with column count, etc., I will try just using 1 and 1, but the fact it works when passing specific numbers shows there are sufficient rows and columns. The error in debug shows up at the line .Cell(rnum,cnum).Range.InsertAfter vText.

Comment: OK. Interesting. If I set rowNum number to 1, then I can write in the 4 columns no problem. When I set rowNum to 2, then it doesn't work. So it seems it has something to do with referencing rows added to the table - perhaps that is changed when a row is added? I'll experiment some more, but still strange it works when I pass numbers.

Comment: So it seems that the code to add a row had somehow the impression there was a 'vertically merged cell'. I made a new table and that worked, even though it's the same as the previous one. Still not sure why it works with specific numbers and not a variable of the same number, but that will likely remain a mystery, as at least I can move on.